# Not sure why I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I have no idea how this is happening.  Last night it worked fine:

My logger on the server reads:

Form Array length  2

Fields= 2

so why am I getting a null if there is a size and length > 1 in the array and list??????

Please help...thanx

Form:

```
  public String[] getFields() 
{ 
    return fields; 
}
public void setFields(String[] s) 
{ 
    fields = s; 
    System.out.println("Form Array length " + s.length);    
}



 String[] formFields = form.getFields(); 


        List<Bean> fields = new ArrayList<Bean>();
        for( String fName : formFields )
        {
            fields.add( BeanCache.fetchFromCache(Bean.class,name) );
        }
        System.out.println("Fields= " + fields.size() );


 for( bean f : fields ) 
        {
           System.out.println("Name = " + f.getName() );  <<-- NULL ERROR HERE???
        }
```

Comment: what line is getting the nullpointer?

Comment: At a guess, the problem lies here: `BeanCache.fetchFromCache` - it's returning a `null`?

Comment: On first glance it looks like you might have an array that contains null elements.

Comment: `System.out.println("Field Name = " + field.getFieldName() );`

Comment: @Nim...you might be right....I have to ask another developer about that section

Comment: What do you see when you debug the code?

Comment: @ Nim...Thanks I should Have put a logger statment in that for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your list contains null values.

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add(null);
System.out.println(stringList.get(0).trim()); // null pointer
```